# Send bought books to kindle as books and not documents

Tags: kindle, send-to-kindle

I bought a book in another store "The Pragmatic Bookshelf" and I want to deliver the content to my Kindle as a Book. When I send to it, it is recognized as Document. Is there a way to do that?

I send the book to the email I set up on Amazon.

Comment: Kindle does not natively support epub, though it can easily read PDF and doc files.

Comment: @idiotprogrammer thank you for your answer and your comment. I uploaded with the mobi format that pragmatic programmers have in their site. I will try to do what you say on mu kindle app, thank you!

Comment: Ran into this as well. Tried a few different file type conversions with calibre but none have worked thus far:
`mobi` -> `azw3` | 
`mobi` -> `azw3` -> `mobi` |
`mobi` -> `mobi` |
`mobi` -> `mobi` + replacing `[PDOC]` in the output options with `[EBOK]` |
`mobi` -> `mobi` + switching type to `new` in the output options (which is `KFX` I believe)

Comment: Unfortunately when it is a `"doc"` type book, the highlights are not saved to the cloud

Comment: in `Manage Content & Devices` it seems that "book" is just a euphamism for paid content, while everything else is lumped in as a "doc" -- even if it's a `mobi` file.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Documents and Books are treated almost identically inside the Kindle app or Kindle device. There are filtering functions to divide the view so you see only one type  or another type, but generally you can see both types together.

One thing: in **Manage Content & Devices**, (on the Amazon website) you need to specify Documents or Books, so you can see files you have uploaded or files which were bought.

Comment: Unfortunately this is not true for the web app at read.kindle.com - which will not show you any Documents